# Scraping through selenium : unable to locate element

Tags: selenium-webdriver

After feeding the search bar with "Safety" keyword, I am trying to get to the page associated with this link_text. But error unable to find element is coming.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import re
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Users\\tanmay\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotel_Review-g304551-d299120-Reviews-or10-The_Lalit_New_Delhi-New_Delhi_National_Capital_Territory_of_Delhi.html")

print("Name :",driver.find_element_by_id("HEADING").text)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='TABS_REVIEWS']/span").click()
Element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("query_elem")
Element.send_keys("Safety")
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.ui_icon.search.search-icon').click()
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,2020);")
driver.find_element_by_link_text(driver.find_element_by_class_name("searchHit").text).click()
```

Comment: Is the element visible on the page when you are trying to click it. And also check if that element is not in a iframe and there is no overlay that block clicking the element.

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on the search icon, there is a AJAX request to fetch the data.
You would need to wait its end to query the text.

One way of doing it easily is to wait for the *searchHit* element to be visible.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10) #10 seconds timeout
searchHit = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".searchHit"))) # Wait until the element is clickable for 10 seconds at most
searchHit.click()
```